# emacs finds one package, not another

Tags: init-file, configuration-files

WHAT WORKS FINE.

When I compile a `.tex` file with `C-c C-c`, `emacs` knows that it should use `pdflatex`.  I don't really know how, because I don't see `pdflatex` in my `.emacs` nor `init.el` (I can't find an `.emacs.el` file).  On the other hand, `which pdflatex` returns the absolute path `/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex` so `emacs` knows where to find it.

WHAT I CAN'T MAKE TO WORK.

I recently `package-install`'ed `markdown-mode`, as well as `pandoc` using `brew install pandoc`.  When I run `C-c C-c m` to compile, I get `markdown failed with exit code 127`.  I think it means that `emacs` is not able to find `pandoc`.  For one thing, `pandoc` is not listed under `package-activated-list`, but I guess it could never be there since `pandoc` is not an `elisp` package (is that correct?).  On the other hand, `which pandoc` returns the absolute path `/usr/local/bin/pandoc` so it's not a problem of `pandoc` not being able to be found.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21819595/9472676)
I could add
`(setq pandoc-binary "/usr/local/bin/pandoc")` in my `.emacs`, but I am not sure where since I don't see any other non-elisp packages included there. But again, I don't see any such line for `pdflatex` in my configuration files (`.emacs` or `init.el`), so this wouldn't answer my question:

How does `emacs` know to use `pdflatex` and not `pandoc`?  In other words, which other files contain further configuration parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You probably use the AUCTeX package to work on .tex files. This package actively searches for some programs related to TeX or LaTeX work. It's authors wrote that.

For markdown-mode this just wasn't done. For whatever reason. Maybe there are just too many different markdown converters out there that it makes sense to let the user decide. Thus, they gave you `markdown-command`. Please note, that `markdown-mode` does'nt use the `pandoc-binary` variable. Use `markdown-command` instead.

TL;DR: You can't really compare the approaches both packages take. One puts more effort into working out of the box, the other doesn't.